# How to change my recursion pattern?

Tags: python, recursion

```
def pet(n,shape):
    if n==1:
        return shape
    else:
        return stack_frac(1/n,scale(1/n,shape),pet(n-1,shape))
```

the scale function changes the size of shape to `1/n`. However, only the first shape is needed to scale to `1/n`. The rest of `n-1` patterns are `2/n, 3/n....n/n`. My recursion changes all the sizes to `1/n, 1/(n-1), 1/(n-2)...`

Is there a way to change the recursion to `2/n, 3/n....n/n`?

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
def pet(n, shape, k=1):
    if k == n: 
        return shape
    else:
        return stack_frac(k/n, scale(k/n, shape), pet(n, shape, k+1))
```